# Python text parsing and saving as html

Tags: python, html, loops

I've been playing around with Python trying to write a script to scan a directory for specific files, finding certain keywords and saving the lines where these keywords appear into a new file. I came up with this;

```
import sys, os, glob

for filename in glob.glob("./*.LOG"):
 with open(filename) as logFile:
 name = os.path.splitext(logFile.name)[0]
 newLOG = open(name + '_ERROR!'+'.LOG', "w")
 allLines = logFile.readlines()
 logFile.close()
 printList = []

 for line in allLines:
    if ('ERROR' in line) or ('error' in line):
     printList.append(line)

 for item in printList:
     # print item    
     newLOG.write(item)
```

This is all good but I thought I'd try instead saving this new file as html wrapping it all in the rights tags(html,head,body...) so that maybe I could change the font colour of the keywords. So far it looks like this;

```
import sys, os, glob

for filename in glob.glob("./*.LOG"):

 with open (filename) as logFile:
     name = os.path.splitext(logFile.name)[0]
     newLOG = open(name + '_ERROR!'+'.html', "w")
     newLOG.write('<html>')
     newLOG.write('<head>')
     newLOG.write('<body><p>')

     allLines = logFile.readlines()
     logFile.close()
     printList = []

     for line in allLines:
        if ('ERROR' in line) or ('error' in line):
         printList.append(line)

     for item in printList:
         # print item 

        newLOG.write('</html>')
        newLOG.write('</head>')
        newLOG.write('</body><p>')   
        newLOG.write(item)
```

Now the problem is I'm new to this and I'm still trying to figure out how to work with indentations and loops.. Because my html tags are being appended from within the loop, every line has the `<html>`, `<head>` & `<body><p>` tag around them and it just looks wrong. I understand the problem and have tried rewriting things so that the tags are applied outside the loop but I've not had much success.

Could someone show me a better way of getting the file name of the current file, creating a new file+appending it as I think this is why I'm getting the file handling errors when trying to change how it all works.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a matter of indenting the lines to the right level. The HTML footer must be printed at the indentation level of the header lines, not indented within the loop. Try this:

```
import sys, os, glob
import cgi

for filename in glob.glob("./*.LOG"):

    name = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
    with open(filename, 'r') as logFile, open('%s_ERROR!.html' % name, 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write("<html>\n<head>\n</head>\n<body><p>")

        allLines = logFile.readlines()
        printList = []

        for line in allLines:
            if ('ERROR' in line) or ('error' in line):
                printList.append(line)

        for item in printList:
            # Note: HTML-escape value of item
            outfile.write(cgi.escape(item) + '<br>')

        outfile.write("</p></body>\n</html>")
```

Note that you don't need to use printList - you could just emit the HTML code as you go through the log.

Consider breaking this into smaller functions for reusability and readability.

Comment: Hi thank for the help, unfortunately I'm not quite there yet. I was getting an EOL related error which was fixed by correcting the quotation on the last line, but now I'm getting an error on the os.path line saying logfile is not defined(understandable), I then tried splitting line 7 and putting "with open(filename, 'r') as logFile" before "name+os.path..." but that in turn throws an error on the remaining of the line; "open(name + '_ERROR!.html', 'w') as outfile:" as invalid syntax =/

Comment: Fixed the error (sorry about that) - please try the updated answer.

Comment: Brilliant thank you! 
Now I just have to figure out how to wrap the keywords in the correct tags so theyre a different colour.
Side question; Is something like this; <font color = "XXXXXX">keyword</font> the best way to go 
or should I go with css.

Thanks again.

Comment: Use CSS if you can.